# Как получить район области

Tags: яндекс-карты

У меня есть код на пхп, написанный несколько лет назад. Эта функция определяем район (города или области) по координатам.

```
    if($c) $kind = 'district';
else $kind = 'area';

$data = simplexml_load_file('https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=МОЙ-КОД&kind='.$kind.'&geocode='.$coord);
```

Но сейчас определение района области не работает (район города определяет).
Начал дебажить и понял что ссылка ...&kind=area&geocode=... больше не работает, возвращает ошибку.

```
<statusCode>400</statusCode>
<error>Bad Request</error>
<message>
Parameter "kind": "kind" must be one of [house, street, metro, district, locality]
</message>
</error>
```

Как теперь определять район области?

Answer (score 0):

Согласно документации в запросе параметр [kind](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/concepts/input_params-docpage/#input_params__format) не принимает значение "area", о чем вам 400 ошибка и сообщает.

Однако, там же в документации есть структура ответа Геокодера, где может присутствовать вложенный компонент ["area"](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/reference/akind-docpage/).

Все что нужно - это фильтровать ответ Геокодера и получить нужный вам параметр.

Отдельно отмечу, Яндекс [запрещает](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geocoder/desc/concepts/limits-docpage/) использовать API без отображения данных на общедоступной карте.